# How to extend a function of a closed subset of a hausdorff space to the total space?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis

This is an exercise in Lang's Real and Functional Analysis Chpt 3, Ex 2. I do not see how to proceed without additional hypothesis e.g. normality.

Let closed set $S\subset X$ where $X$ is hausdorff. Denote $J\subset C(X)$ ideal of all real valued continuous function on $X$ vanishing on $S$. Equip $C(X)$ with sup norm. Then $J$ is closed ideal under sup norm. (Pick sequence $f_n\in J, f_n\to f$ under sup norm. Then it is clear that every point of $f$ cannot deviate too far from $f_n$ for $n$ large. Then this implies every point $x\in S$ $f(x)$ has to be arbitrarily small by $f_n|S=0$. Then it follows that $J$ is closed ideal.

I have trouble to establish isomorphism between $C(X)/J$ and $C(S)$ under hypothesis $X$ being hausdorff and $S$ closed.

It is clear that $C(X)\to C(S)$ by restriction and $J= Ker(C(X)\to C(S))$ by definition of $J$. The injectivity of $C(X)/J\to C(S)$ follows easily. Then the task would be extending $f\in C(S)$ to $C(X)$ with appropriate representative. However, this is normally achieved by normal condition on $X$ which allows application of Tietze extension Thm. Then the isomorphism follows trivially.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Did I miss anything here? How should I proceed to check $C(X)/J\to C(S)$ is surjection? Hint will be sufficient. Or if $X$ is compact, there might be hope to approximate the function in the image and use completeness to deduce this is an element in the image.

Comment: If $X$ is compact, then compact Hausdorff implies normal. Also Tietze extension theorem is equivalent to normality, so you should need some additional assumption, yes. $X$ Hausdorff and $S$ closed is insufficient.

Comment: @jgon Yes. If $X$ is compact, then normality follows easily by finding coverings and finiteness argument. Why Tietze extension theorem is equivalent to normality as I have not seen such argument? And if compactness is dropped, what is the counter example? Thanks.

Comment: For Tietze extension theorem equivalent to normality, I'll assume normality implies extension as given. For the converse, let $A$, $B$, be disjoint closed subsets of $X$. Then we can define $f(a)=0$, $f(b)=1$ for $a\in A$, $b\in B$, which is a continuous function on $A\cup B$. Extending $f$ to $X$ and getting $F$ and taking the preimages $F^{-1}(-1,1/2)$ and $F^{-1}(1/2,2)$, we get disjoint open neighborhoods of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: As for compactness, compactness is not required for Lang's proposition here, just normality. I was just saying that if $X$ is compact, then we get normality and thus the Tietze extension theorem.

Comment: Also in case it wasn't clear, the Tietze extension theorem for $X$ is equivalent to Lang's proposition being true for all closed subsets $S$ of $X$. Thus my claim that normality is in fact required.

Comment: @jgon I see. Thanks a lot for clarification.